# Using loop to compare a value in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to filter all values where T becomes 1, and when the value reaches 0, i need to record '10' time instances before dropping other zeros in the list.

i thought of using if and while loop combination, create a filter column and delete values based on this

```
counter = 0
if df["T"] = 1 : 
    df["Filter"] = 1
else:
    while df["T"] =0 :
        if counter <=10:
            df["Filter"] = 1
        else:
            df["F"] = 0
        counter = counter +1
```

I'm getting following error

```
    if df["T"] = 1 :
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

help me

I have tried to explain the issue in more detail

I'm new to coding, and thought the above loop would result in something.
I will show the problem statement and explain the desired outcome.
"T" is an output from a sensor, when the sensor detects something the output will be 1, and 0 if none.
Current data has long sensor idle state ("0"), i want to drop the sensor output data with long idle (more than 10 sec)
[Input signal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa6Cy.png)

"also, can anyone suggest me course or a book from practical view point to learn pandas and python"

Comment: Try `==`not `=`.

Answer (score 0):

When assigning a value to a variable, you use a single `=`. When checking if a value is equal to some value you need two equal signs: `==`. But I am not sure if this code does what you want as `df["T"] == 1` will raise an error as it does not return `True` or `False`. Rather it will return a `pd.Series`.

Probably, something you want to do is:

```
df.loc[df["T"] == 1, 'Filter'] = 1
```

This will set `Filter` to 1 when `T` is equal to 1.

```
counter = 0
if df["T"] == 1 : 
    df["Filter"] = 1
else:
    while df["T"] == 0 :
        if counter <= 10:
            df["Filter"] = 1
        else:
            df["F"] = 0
        counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: Actually, since `df["T"] == 1` returns a `pd.Series`, the line `if df["T"] == 1:` will throw an error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` It will be better for the OP to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and also show us what the desired output is. Unlikely that a loop of this kind is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted correctly, you have to put the field `['Filter]` equal to 1 if `['T']` is 1 OR if `['T']` is 0 and it is one of the first 10 results.

The right way to write an equality if is with `==`: `if a == b:`
But in your case, even if you had written it correctly, an error would have risen, because you can't ask Python to tell if a `pd.Series` (`df['T']`) is equal to an `int`.
Another problem of your code is with the use of the variable `counter`: if you start from 0 and put the if condition as `if counter <= 10:`, you will replace 11 occurrencies, not 10.

What I would do is:

```
df['Filter'] = 0
df.loc[(df.groupby('T').cumcount() <10) | df['T'] == 1, 'Filter'] = 1
```

Comment: should i create an pd.series of df["1"] = 1 , and use that to compare with df["t"] ?
how should i compare with dataframe with int/float